# Sending a calendar value using POST into next page

Tags: php, html

I have an `<input type="date" name="Date"/>` in my `<form method="post" ... >`, and I want to take the selected value from this calendar transform it into `YYYY-MM-DD` format and then post it into my next page.
Is their any help ?

Comment: Try using a date and time picker, if you are using bootstrap, you can use this, it is good, https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/,

Comment: Simply post it and get it on the page where you are posting it and the format will be what you want.

Comment: Notepad++ what framework is that?! I am using Netbeans

Comment: I don't know how to post value of calendar and transform it into YYYY-MM-DD, I searched it and can't find a solution

Comment: Search for how to deal with POSTS in PHP and then search how to deal with dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snippet for your idea, modify to fit your need:

index.php

```
<form method="post" action="next.php">
    <input type="date" name="Date"/>
    <button>done</button>
</form>
```

next.php

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['Date']));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can deal with the date as it gets posted in the form action page:

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

NOTE: make sure you are protecting yourself from SQL injection in the resultant page if there is to be any DB interaction.

Comment: I am using PDO coding, but is their any extra to add and write ?

Comment: There shouldn't be as this is pure PHP, the PDO comes in when interacting with the DB in which case 'YYYY-mm-dd' format should give you the correct format for MySQL. TBH I use codeigniter which takes care of all the DB stuff and dont do a lot of pure PDO, good luck

Answer (score 1):

get the text box value and format('Y-m-d h:i:s') then store in hidden textbox and post the value.